# Pointing some file from the parent directory in PHP

Tags: php

I am using `XAMPP` server in my local machine. Let's assume my directory structure is as below

```
-api/
  - products.php
-includes/
  - settings.php
```

So from `products.php` page if I want to include `settings.php` file then I use `include './includes/settings.php';` in my `local machine`, and it works fine. But when I move it to the remote server then I have to use `include '../includes/settings.php';`. The difference is `./` and `../`. Why this differ in local and remote server and what is the solution ..??

Comment: That relative path absolutely should not work on your local machine either.  I suspect there's something you're missing.

Comment: It should always be ../ so something's different in your setup

Answer (score 0):

to avoid any problems try to use **DIR** it will give you the path compared to where your current file exist, also try to use include_once instead of include.

> **DIR** : The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the
>   directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to
>   dirname(FILE). This directory name does not have a trailing slash
>   unless it is the root directory.

```
include_once __DIR__.'/../includes/settings.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be some difference between how your local machine and your server sees directory structure. One way to get around this is to use namespaces and "use" statements.

In your products.php at the top of the class page create a namespace. Something like:

```
namespace YourProject\Api;

use YourProject\Includes\Settings;
```

And in your settings.php class use a namespace (and any use statements you may need.) Something like:

```
namespace YourProject\Includes;

use YourProject\Api\Products;
```

You can then create new objects that you may need such as in your settings class:

```
$products = new Products();
```

Or in your products class:

```
$settings = new Settings();
```

Check [Namespace and Importing from the PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) for more info.